# UIWebView loading time

Tags: ios, uiwebview, load

I've got webView and I try to handle case with bad connection. WebView tries to load content during 5 mins without connection and sends error after.

**How can I change time of loading to 1 min for example?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try **performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:**

When it starts loading:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
  [self performSelector:@selector(stop_bad_link) withObject:nil afterDelay:60.0 ];
}
```

If loaded successfully:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
 [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(stop_bad_link) object:nil];
}
```

If its a bad link:

```
-(void)stop_bad_link{
 if([webView isLoading]!=NO)[webView stopLoading];
}
```

Comment: What if the web view is loading some other webpage that the user selected 60 seconds later? Won't this just kill that? If so then this is not an acceptable answer.